# Best practice for html tags in vue-i18n translations?

Tags: localization, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using `vue-i18n` and I need to translate a sentence with an anchor tag in the middle. Obviously I want to keep the html specific markup out of my translations, but how best to handle this?

Consider the following example:

```
This is a test sentence which cannot 
<a href="https://example.com" class="test-class test-another-class">be split</a> 
or it will not make sense
```

The only solution I can come up with is:

```
{
    "en": {
        "example": "This is a test sentence which cannot {linkOpen}be split{linkClose} or it will not make sense"
    }
}
```

and then in the component template

```
<p v-html="$t('example', { 
    'linkOpen': `<a href="https://example/com" class="test-class test-another-class">`,
    'linkClose: '</a>'
    }) 
"></p>
```

Not exactly elegant however...

Edit: I've tested this and it doesn't actually work (can't put html in params) so now I'm really out of ideas!

Comment: A simple replace like this `$t('id').replace('<a>', '<a href='my link'>')` works for me. Then I just set my translatable text to: `My <a>text</a> works`.

Answer (score 2):

You can come up with some simple markup for links and write a small transformation function, for example:

```
//In this example links are structured as follows [[url | text]]

var text = `This is a test sentence which 
cannot [[https://example.com | be split]] or it will not make sense`

var linkExpr = /\[\[(.*?)\]\]/gi;
var linkValueExpr = /(\s+\|\s+)/;

var transformLinks = (string) => {
  return text.replace(linkExpr, (expr, value) => {
    var parts = value.split(linkValueExpr);
    var link = `<a href="${parts[0]}">${parts[2]}</a>`;

    return link;
  });
}

alert(transformLinks(text));
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ru5smdy3/

With `vue-i18n` it will look like this (which of course you can simplify):

```
<p v-html="transformLinks($t('example'))"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the HTML into an element that is not part of the displayed DOM and then extract its `textContent`. This may not work for what you're actually trying to do, though. I can't tell.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    html: `This is a test sentence which cannot 
<a href="https://example.com" class="test-class test-another-class">be split</a> 
or it will not make sense`,
    utilityEl: document.createElement('div')
  },
  methods: {
    htmlToText: function (html) {
      this.utilityEl.innerHTML = html;
      return this.utilityEl.textContent;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p v-html="html"></p>
  <p>{{htmlToText(html)}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found myself in a similar situation, and I propose using Vue-i18n [slots](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html#slots-syntax-usage).

I have a JSON i18n file which had error messages that were html. These rendered fine but they [will not be compiled as vue templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html), and cannot have bindings. I want to call an onclick function when users click the link in a given error message.

In my example I have a cake-state json with some status messages:

```
// cake_state.json, where I want links in error messages to call a function when clicked
{
  "state":{
        "stage": {
            "mixing": "Cake is being mixed. The current time is {time}",
            "resting": "Cake is resting. The current time is {time}",
            "oven": "Cake is cooking. The current time is {time}"
            },
        "error": {
            "ovenIssue": "Oven of brand is malfunctioning. Click {email_support_link} to get help",
            "chefIssue": "Chef is down. Click {email_support_link} to get help",
            "leakIssue": "There is a leak"
            },
  }
}
```

Now if we have some Vue SFC, with the template as such:

```
<template>
   <div>
     <i18n :path="getMessage">
        <!-- enter various i18n slots -->
        <template #time>
          <span>{{ getTime }}</span>
        </template>
        
        <template #email_support_link>
          <!-- binding now works because it is not v-html -->
          <a href="" @click.prevent="getRightSupportDepartment">here</span>
        </template>
       </i18n>
    </div>
</template>

...

// js
computed: {
    getTime(): string { //implementation ...},
    getRightSupportDepartment(): string { //implementation ...},
    
    //return strings that are keys to cake_state.json messages
    getMessage(): string {
        ...
        switch (this.cakeState) {
          case Failure.Overheat:
            return "state.error.ovenIssue";
          case Failure.ChefIdle:
            return "state.error.chefIssue";
          case Failure.LeakSensor:
            return "state.error.leakIssue";
```

So what we see here is:

1. the `getMessage` function provides us the key to the message in the i18n JSON. This is passed into `i18n` component
2. the `<template #XXX>` slots in the `i18n` component's scope are supplied with this key from the function, which gets the corresponding message, and then
3. if the relevant message has any of the keywords, it gets put in from the corresponding template.

To re-iterate, it helps to provide a means to have vue bindings to html elements which would otherwise be served from the i18n json as raw html.

For example now we might see "Oven of brand is malfunctioning. Click [here](http://nowhere) to get help", and we can run an onclick function when user clicks 'here'.

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm using i18n for a long time and didn't know they had slots.
This is they correct and cleanest answer.